# JQ search object with regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, jq

I've been playing around with JQ https://jqplay.org to extract JSON data and I saw the `test` operation that allows me to use regex to extract data. In below sample run, I passed in regex pattern `"^progressive$"` into `test` to search for data:

**DATA**:

```
[
  {"genre": "progressive"},
  {"genre": "a progressive 1"}
]
```

**QUERY**:

```
map(select(.genre | test("^progressive$")))
```

**RESULT**:

```
[
  {
    "genre": "progressive"
  }
]
```

==========================================================================

Now, I want to do opposite above. `genre` value in the JSON is my regex and what I pass in `test` is my data. For example:

**DATA**:

```
[
  {"genre": "^progressive$"},
  {"genre": "^abc$"}
]
```

**QUERY**:

I have not figured out the query yet :( but I have tried following but it did not return what I want or error out.

```
map(select("progressive" | test(.["genre"])))
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
[
  {
    "genre": "^progressive$"
  }
]
```

I don't know if it is possible to do or if anyone knows howto. I'm thinking of doing the long way which will loop through each object in array and extract `genre` value out and then compared with `progressive`. This is a long way and it will work but I'm curious if anyone knows a better and more efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: @chepner thanks for pointing out my error, yes, I just updated my expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to be what you're after:

```
map(. as $in | select("progressive" | test($in|.["genre"])))
```

(`$in|.["genre"]` can be abbreviated to `$in.genre` but I left the pipe to make things a bit clearer.)

Notice how we use `. as $in` to set things up so we can call `test` with the appropriate input and argument.

### Variation

A little less typing ...

```
map(.genre as $g | select("progressive" | test($g)))
```

Comment: both solution works except a case when data has single `*` . For example: `[
  {"genre": "*"},
  {"genre": "^abc$"}
]` . Any idea how to handle this corner case? @peak

Comment: "*" is not a valid regex.  To ignore the error, you could write `test($g)?`